# extracting multiple zips/rar into same folder

Tags: zip

maybe I am stupid, but I just cant figure out how to extract multiple zips into the same folder easy.

I always end up with folders of the zip name that then has the content in it... this is really annoying.

Is there a app that does this automatically?

thx

Answer (score 1):

One real easy way is to use `unzip` on the command line.

**1)** If the ZIP file doesn't contain any folder hierarchy, simply files at the "root" level of the compressed file, do this:

1. open Terminal and `cd` to the folder with the ZIP file
2. `unzip zipfile.zip`

-> The files are extracted directly into that folder.

**2)** If the ZIP file does contain a folder hierarchy, but you *still* want to extract everything in the same folder (usually not a good idea, as the hierarchy is there probably for a reason), do the same thing as above, but with `-j` modifier for unzip, which means "junk paths (do not make directories)":

```
unzip -j zipfile.zip
```

**Edit**: the same approach works for RAR files, except you'd need to install the [command-line unrar tool](https://superuser.com/questions/52124/whats-a-good-way-to-extract-rar-files-on-the-mac/52207#52207) yourself (unlike with unzip), and I'm not sure what the equivalent for unzip's -j modifier is.

Comment: thanks, but there must be a app does doesn't require command line input :/